# What are "LedgerEntry objects" and "Asset pairs" in relation to Stellar Core Configuration?

Tags: stellar-core, stellar.toml, asset-pairs

The following is mentioned in the example config but I am wondering what a LedgerEntry object and Asset pair actually are, in this context.

```
# Data layer cache configuration
# - ENTRY_CACHE_SIZE controls the maximum number of LedgerEntry objects
#   that will be stored in the cache (default 4096)
# - BEST_OFFERS_CACHE_SIZE controls the maximum number of Asset pairs that
#   will be stored in the cache, although many LedgerEntry objects may be
#   associated with a single Asset pair (default 64)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/ledger.html:

> The ledger is a collection of entries. Currently there are 4 types of ledger entries. They’re specified in [src/xdr/Stellar-ledger-entries.x](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/src/xdr/Stellar-ledger-entries.x).
>
> - Account entry
>   This entry represents an account. In Stellar, everything is built around accounts: transactions are performed by accounts, and accounts control the access rights to balances.
> - Trustline entry
>   Trustlines are lines of credit the account has given a particular issuer in a specific currency.
> - Offer entry
>   Offers are entries that an account creates in the orderbook.
> - Data entry
>   Data entries are key value pairs attached to an account. They allow account controllers to attach arbitrary data to their account.

---

`BEST_OFFERS_CACHE_SIZE` in theory should control an in-memory cache size for trading pairs, like `XLM <> BTC-GAHK..0P2N`. As far as I can tell from the source code, best offers cache is used by "in-memory transaction-in-progress" internally to cache offers consumed by current transaction.

Comment: Do you know what determines the values I should use for those configs? If we are running a stellar node(on AWS EC2) that is archiving ledgers and has a horizon api, what advantages/problems are there with changing these cache values from the default? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have never changed the default settings. From my experience, the disks I/O is usually a bottleneck, as PostgreSQL performs **a lot** read/write operations, especially during the initial catchup.